# Phaser JS + Phonegap and Ads - AdMob or iAd

Tags: cordova, html5-canvas, admob, phonegap-plugins, phaser-framework

I have spend the last 2 days trying to get Ad's working on my HTML5 Phaser JS game.

Im using this plugin:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

The plugin is installed as far as I can tell

config.xml has the below:

```
<feature name="AdMob">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAdMobPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

When I run my code in Xcode I get the below, which confirm the plugin is working fine.

```
2015-06-07 11:22:03.071 Marty[13191:1120217] [CDVTimer][admob] 0.136971ms
2015-06-07 11:22:03.071 Marty[13191:1120217] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.307977ms
```

I am using the below code in my `deviceReady` function to start a test banner ad. However, nothing is displayed.

```
var enabledAdMob = true;

    if (enabledAdMob) {
      AdMob.createBanner({
        adId: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX?XXXXXXXXX",
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        offsetTopBar: true,
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true
      });



    }
```

If I use the exact same code and same plugin with a non Phaser JS Phonegap application it works fine and I get this in the console.

```
2015-06-07 11:28:26.273 appname[13452:1152164] [CDVTimer][admob] 0.143945ms
2015-06-07 11:28:26.273 appname[13452:1152164] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 93.865991ms
2015-06-07 11:28:26.302 appname[13452:1152164] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-06-07 11:28:26.894 appname[13452:1152164] createBanner
2015-06-07 11:28:26.969 appname[13452:1152164] request.testDevices: 9e788a4b970dc9e34b3830c67dcf7f7e, <Google> tips handled
2015-06-07 11:28:27.530 appname[13452:1152164] Finished load of: file:///folder/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C900F3B1-2299-493A-BF66-BC97119BBBD8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/app.app/www/index.html
2015-06-07 11:28:27.951 appname[13452:1152164] AdMob, onAdLoaded, {'adNetwork':'AdMob','adType':'banner','adEvent':'onAdLoaded'}
2015-06-07 11:28:27.951 appname[13452:1152164] statusbar offset:0.000000, overlap:0, ad position:8, x:0, y:0
2015-06-07 11:28:27.952 appname[13452:1152164] window, resize,
```

And the Ad is visible and working fine.

I have tried many many variations on where I place the createBanner method, however nothing seems to work.

I am desperately in need of assistance from someone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo for Phaser and AdMob:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-game-phaser/tree/master/demo

You can copy the js/admob.js to your project, and simply reference to it in your index.html

Comment: Thanks Raymond. Your a legend.